# Area between Graphs

Tags: calculus

> Let $S(k)$ denote the area between the line  $y = kx + 1$ and $y = x^2 + 2x - 3,$ where $k$ varies across the real numbers.
> Find the least value of $S(k).$

I've tried doing it algebraically, but this is quite long.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this very quickly (in under 2 min) - I'm asking because it come up in an exam where we have around this much time per question.
Many thanks in advance :).

Comment: What value did you get with your calculation?

Comment: I think that the minimum must be 0. It is when the two lines have just 1 intersection point, i. e. The straight line is a tangent line to the parabola. This is when te quadratic equation $x^2+2x-3k=kx+1$ has only one solution.

Comment: @kmitov It seems you've misread the equation of parabola, there is no $k.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT
This solution looks elegant, but doesn't hold for every real $k.$

---

$S(k)$ is the area of the domain above the parabola $y = x^2 + 2x - 3$ and below the line $y = kx + 1,$ or is infinite.
Each of lines passes through the point $(0,1),$ which lies inside the parabola, to the right of its axis. For each value of $k< 0$ is the portion above the horizontal (red) line $y=1$ and below the actual line $y=kx+1$ larger than the portion below $y=1$ and above $y=kx+1.$ (Naturally, the "portions" are also limited by a piece of parabola, but this doesn't influence which one is larger.) Therefore $$\forall k\le 0, S(k)\geq S(0).$$
$S(0)$ is the minimum and can be calculated quickly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$S(k)$ is the area of the domain above the parabola $y = x^2 + 2x - 3$ and below the line $y = kx + 1,$ or is infinite. Each of lines passes through the point $(0,1)$  inside the parabola, therefore there are two points of intersection (line $\cap$ parabola). The area is
$$\begin{eqnarray}S(k)=&\int_{a_k}^{b_k}kx+1-(x^2 + 2x - 3)dx\\\\=& \left[-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{(k-2)x^2}{2}+4x\right]_{a_k}^{b_k},\end{eqnarray}$$ where $a_k\le b_k$ are solutions of the equation $$kx+1=x^2 + 2x - 3. \tag{1}$$
The discriminant of $(1)$ $$D=(k-2)^2+16>0,$$ the two real solutions are
$$a_k=\frac{(k-2)-\sqrt{D}}{2},\quad b_k=\frac{(k-2)+\sqrt{D}}{2} $$
The following will help:
$$a_k+b_k=k-2,\quad b_k-a_k=\sqrt{D},\quad a_kb_k=-4,\quad a_k^2+b_k^2=(k-2)^2+8.$$ Thus

$$\begin{eqnarray}S(k)&=&\frac{(b_k-a_k)}{6}\bigg(-2(b_k^2+a_kb_k+a_k^2)+3(k-2)(a_k+b_k)+24\bigg)\\&=&\frac{\sqrt{D}}{6}\times D\end{eqnarray}$$
Therefore $$S(k)=\frac{\big((k-2)^2+16\big)^{3/2}}{6},$$ which is minimal for $k=2.$ The minimal value is $$S(2)=\frac{32}{3}.$$